# Excel formula help - I have 14/28 day readings averaged per day which need to be recorded as daily readings

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Dates when the data was read are shown on the date column on the left, then worked out a value per day shown in ET/DAY column.

To analyze monthly data etc etc I want daily data so every day has the ET/DAY value between the dates it was read and inserted in the et/day column.

I have entered in manually what I want in blue but need a formula to do this as too long to do all manually

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `MATCH`. With an ascending list, if you give the magic number `1` as the third parameter, it will show the last row number with a smaller or equal number.

Here it's matched 17 with 15 in column A and the result is 2, for row 2:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |  | `=MATCH(17,A:A,1)` = 2 |
| 2 | 15 |  |  |
| 3 | 20 |  |  |

So for your data, you can match the daily dates with the column on the left, and feed the row number into `INDEX` to look up from the ET/Day column.

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Date | ET/Day |  | Daily | ET/Day |
| 2 | 05/Jan/1995 |  |  | 05/Jan/1995 | `=Index(B:B, Match(@D:D,A:A,1))` = #N/A |
| 3 | 19/Jan/1995 | 3.00 |  | 06/Jan/1995 | `=Index(B:B, Match(@D:D,A:A,1))` = 3.00 |
| 4 | 02/Feb/1995 | 5.41 |  | 07/Jan/1995 | `=Index(B:B, Match(@D:D,A:A,1))` = 3.00 |
| 5 |  |  |  | ... | ... |
| 6 |  |  |  | 19/Jan/1995 | `=Index(B:B, Match(@D:D,A:A,1))` = 3.00 |
| 7 |  |  |  | 20/Jan/1995 | `=Index(B:B, Match(@D:D,A:A,1))` = 5.41 |

There's an inconsistency here with the 05 Jan rate but it should be good after that.